# Cloudmask in Landsat 8 images

Tags: r, landsat-8

Can someone please tell me how will I discard the clouds from Landsat 8 images using R? I have used the code

```
LC08_20151128_new <- cloudMask(LC08_20151128, threshold = 0.8, blue = "layer.1", tir = "layer.9", buffer = NULL, plot = FALSE)
```

I read that for landsat 8 layer 1 and layer 9 might be useful to detect the clouds. Is it correct? I got the image below after runninng the code

[image: LC08_20151128_new]

And then I masked the image with the cloudMask

```
LC08_20151128_crop <- mask(LC08_20151128,LC08_20151128_new, maskvalue = NA)
```

But it seems that the code retains the area with the cloud cover instead of removing it. Please see the RGB image below

[image: LC08_20151128_crop]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code provides a reproducible example using the Landsat 8 scene 'LC08_L1TP_195025_20130707_20170503_01_T1' (Collection 1 Level-1) which is roughly centered on Frankfurt am Main, Germany, and was downloaded from [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). In order to discard all cloudy pixels (ie set them to `NA`), which I assume is your overall goal, specify either

- `maskvalue = 1` or
- `maskvalue = NA, inverse = TRUE`

inside your `raster::mask()` call. Have a look at the function's [help pages](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.5-8/topics/mask) for further details.

```
library(satellite)
library(RStoolbox)

## sample data
lc08 = list.files("LC08_L1TP_195025_20130707_20170503_01_T1", 
                  pattern = ".TIF$", full.names = TRUE)
lc08 = sortFilesLandsat(lc08)
lc08 = stack(lc08[c(1:7, 9:11)]) # stack without band 8 (15 m)

## clip image
rext = extent(c(530824, 563455, 5518663, 5545203))
lc08 = crop(lc08, rext)

## mask clouds and visualize
cmsk = cloudMask(lc08, threshold = .4, blue = 2, tir = 9) # bands 2, 10
wocl = mask(lc08, cmsk$CMASK, maskvalue = 1)

library(mapview)
viewRGB(wocl, r = 4, g = 3, b = 2)
```

[image: viewRGB]

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Do I need to crop the original image with    woc1? Or should I continue my analysis with with it? I have used the code you suggested but it did not remove the cloud

Comment: In my example, `wocl` contains the original image with clouds removed (see resulting image created by `mapview::viewRGB`), which is likely what you are aiming at. In case the clouds haven't been captured in your particular case, make sure to have a look at `plot(cmsk)` and adjust `threshold` to the range of NDTCI accordingly (see `?cloudMask`).

Comment: Many thanks for your help. This is really very useful.